# Natural $\sigma$-algebra on the co-domain of a stochastic flow

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Say that we have a stochastic local flow $X$. This is a map that sends $\omega$ into a collection of maps $\phi_{s,t}$ on $s,t\in \mathbb{R}$ which form a 
[local flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_(mathematics)).

I don't understand how $X$ formally defines a random variable. What is the image space, now that the collection does not have the same domain, and what is $\sigma$-algebra?